# What's the effect of doubling the data and copying the data for Lasso Regression and Ridge Regression on standard error?

Tags: lasso, ridge-regression

Suppose we have a dataset $X$, where each piece data of $X$ is a row vector, and the data generation process satisfies Gaussian-Markov assumption. If we do ridge regression on $Y\sim 2X$, how does the regression coefficients and their standard errors change comparing with the regression result when $Y\sim X$? (This is we double each input.) If we we do ridge regression on $[Y ,Y]^T\sim [X, X]^T$, how does the regression coefficients and their standard errors change comparing with the regression result when $Y\sim X$? (This is we copy each input.) What are the answer to above two questions if we ask for Lasso regression instead of ridge regression?

For the coefficient change case for both models, this is not very hard. Note that the loss functions are

$$\min \|X\hat{\beta} - y\|_2^2 + \lambda \|\hat{\beta}\|_p^p$$

for a given instance $y$. If we double the dataset (call the new dataset $(X' = 2X, y'= 2y)$), we have

$$\min \|X'\hat{\beta} - y'\|_2^2 + \lambda \|\hat{\beta}\|_p^p = \min 4\|X\hat{\beta} - y\|_2^2 + \lambda \|\hat{\beta}\|_p^p$$

So it's equivalent to do the same regression on old dataset with a quarter of the old $\lambda$.

If we copy the dataset (call the new dataset $(X' = [X, X]^T, y'= [y, y]^T)$), we have

$$\min \|X'\hat{\beta} - y'\|_2^2 + \lambda \|\hat{\beta}\|_p^p = \min 2\|X\hat{\beta} - y\|_2^2 + \lambda \|\hat{\beta}\|_p^p$$

So it's equivalent to do the same regression on old dataset with a half of the old $\lambda$.

My question is, how about standard error change?

For ridge regression, we have closed-form standard error formula

$$SE^2(\hat{\beta}) = \sigma^2[(X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1} - \lambda(X^T X + \lambda I)^{-2}]$$

So double the dataset gives us

$$SE^2(\hat{\beta}) = \sigma^2[(4X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1} - \lambda(4X^T X + \lambda I)^{-2}]$$

and copy the dataset gives us

$$SE^2(\hat{\beta}) = \sigma^2[(2X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1} - \lambda(2X^T X + \lambda I)^{-2}]$$

Does anyone has some intuition? For OLS, the intuition is simply divide the SE by 2 and by $\sqrt{2}$ respectively.

Also, since Lasso regression doesn't have a closed form solution, any insights to this question?

For context, this is just a problem that I come up with, so maybe there's no good answer to this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why not try it and then tell us what happens?

Comment: Ridge regression usually consists of identifying a suitable $\lambda$ at the same time.  Why would the $\lambda$ for the original dataset and the doubled dataset have the same value??